# Autofac and ASP .NET MVC bad lifetime scope in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

i have external controller (for e.g. ExtController ) in another assembly ( folder config/extensions ).

Registration:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(assembly).Named<IController>(t => 
    t.Name.Replace("Controller", string.Empty)
);
```

Getting a controller ( i have own controller factory ):

```
public override IController CreateController
            (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) 
{
     try
     {
         var ctrl = _base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
         return ctrl;         
      }
      catch (HttpException htte)
      {
          Object ic = null;
          if (_container.TryResolveNamed(controllerName, typeof(IController), out ic))
          {
              return ic as IController;
          } 
          else
              throw htte;
     }             
 }
```

And if i doing request for this controller i get "root" autofac lifetime scope.
In other controllers i got "AutofacWebrequest" scope.

Could you help me ? Maybe is another way for controller creation from another assembly ?

**Edit**

I resolved my problem but i think is not the best way i can do it.
I changed from:

```
if (_container.TryResolveNamed(controllerName, typeof(IController), out ic))
```

to:

```
if ( (DependencyResolver.Current as Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver).RequestLifetimeScope.TryResolveNamed(controllerName, typeof(IController), out ic))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, if your integration point is a custom controller factory working against named services, you are probably stuck with what you have.** You can use `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current` rather than casting `DependencyResolver.Current` yourself, but the principle will still be the same.

However, I did notice you didn't show what the base ControllerFactory is. It appears you have a sort of decorator pattern going with `_base` being called rather than `base` (without the underscore). The `DefaultControllerFactory` already runs controller instantiation through the dependency resolver. Of course, that would mean you need to *not* register controllers as *named* services and instead just register them with the standard `RegisterControllers` method.

Again, if you have to register them named (for whatever reason) and/or if the base call to `CreateController` isn't going through the standard `DefaultControllerFactory`, then what you have is correct. If you can stop registering controllers as named services, though, the standard dependency resolution pipeline will "just work" and you won't need all the extra code.

[There is detailed documentation on Autofac MVC integration on the Autofac doc site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html)